# I need for dataset of malware and benign binaries

Tags: dataset

I am working on the behavior of the malicious functions. I need a large dataset of malware and benign binaries. There exist some resources where the dataset is not available. while some of the available resources have binary datasets not more than 5 to 6 thousand. Do you know any resource where I can find binaries for malware and benign software? The dataset should be more than 12,000 for both.

Comment: You might want to ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ or maybe even https://security.stackexchange.com/ (not sure). Try to fix the English if possible.